# One time per box

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

```
                             []||[]|||[]|[]|||[]||[]
                             []|[][][]||[]|[]|[][][][][]|[]|[]|||[]|[]
                             []||[][][][][][][][]|[]|[][][][]|[][][]|[][][][][]|
                             []|[][][]|[]|[][]|[][]|[]|[][]|||[]|[]
                             []|[]|[]||||[][]|[][][]|[][]||[]|||[]|||
```

---

Finish the sentence below with the help of the puzzle above.

**I solved this puzzle by going......**.

Hint 1

> A little *bit* of converting

Comment: I have a feeling the answer is “out of the box” or something along those lines, but can’t prove it… +1.

Comment: Are the white margins around the boxes part of the puzzle?

Comment: @AxiomaticSystem No they're not part of the puzzle, you can ignore those.

Comment: @Prim3numbah Any hints?

Comment: @Techidiot Sure. Added a hint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this puzzle by going...

> in four different directions !

Daniel S already solved the first part so we just needed to solve the bottom part :

> The [] can be replaced with 0 and the | can be replaced with 1. So we have :
>
>  01101110101110110
>  01000110101000001010111010
>  01100000000101000010001000001
>  010001010010010100111010
>  0101011110010001001101110111

And the next step :

> We can convert the binary numbers to decimal numbers :
>
>  56694
>  18514618
>  201491521
>  4531514
>  91820919

To get letters :

> We put spaces in the right places and convert the numbers to letters with a1z26 :
>
>  EFFID
>  RENFR
>  TNIOU
>  DECON
>  IRTIS

By using the path found by Daniel S, we have the answer :

> IN FOUR DIFFERENT DIRECTIONS

Comment: Nice job! Tick incoming

Comment: Bravo! Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure

> Of the significance of the Square brackets and Pipes

...but I solved this puzzle by going.....

> from the centre square according to the direction indicated by the colour: URDRUULLLLDRDLDDRURDRURDR (or perhaps NESENNWWWWSESWSSENESENESE) before exiting to the yellow triangle.

The title

> May be an indication that the solution is a Hamiltonian path

Comment: Nice job. You got the first part. Once you figure out how to interpret the bottom part of the puzzle ("[ ]" and "|") you'll find the specific phrase that's missing.